# Mark As Read not updating Unread notification count as expected

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I have an in app notification icon in the Navbar that displays the amount of unread notifications.

[image]

Each notification in the dropdown has a "View Request" link. When the user clicks this link it must mark the notification as read and then redirect the user to the relevant page depending on which notification was clicked. The user can also choose to only mark that specific notification as read if they don't want to be redirected.

[image]

When the user clicks on "Mark as Read" the page redirects back and the number is decremented by 1, as expected. However, when the user clicks on "View Request", the page redirects to the relevant page but the number doesn't decrement. I can see in the database that the "read_at" value is definitely updated. Only once the page is refreshed will the number decrement be shown. Could it be that the page redirects before the database query can be executed? I use a single route closure to handle this. If the user clicks on "Mark as Read", the "leavenr" variable is simply passed as "null", otherwise if the user clicks on "View Request" it passes the actual number. My code is below:

web.php

```
Route::get('/markasread/{id}/{leavenr}', function($id, $leavenr){
    auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('id', $id)->first()->markAsRead();

    if($leavenr !== "null"){
        return view('leave.show', ['leavereqs' => Leave::where('leavenr', $leavenr)->first()]);
    } else{
        return redirect()->back();
    }
})->name('markasread');
```

app.blade.php 
(I've omitted most of the redundant code. The below is the only code relevant to this problem)

```
<!-- Show number of unread messages next to notification icon -->
@if(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->count() > 0)
    <span class="badge badge-danger"> {{ auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->count() }} </span>
 @endif
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div style="font-size: 90%; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:10px;">
    <b>{{ $notification->data['requested_by'] }}</b> submitted a new <b>{{ $notification->data['duration'] }}</b> day leave request. <a class="notification-link" href="{{ route('markasread', ['id' => $notification->id, 'leavenr' => $notification->data['leavenr']]) }}" style="color:red">View request</a>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; font-size: 12px;">
    <a class="notification-link" href="{{ route('markasread', ['id' => $notification->id, 'leavenr' => "null"]) }}"><i class="fa fa-check"> Mark as read</i></a>
</div>
<div class="text-right" style="font-size: 12px;">
    <a class="notification-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"> Created: {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($notification->created_at)->format('Y/m/d') }}</i></a>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I've noticed that if I simply use `return redirect()->back();` instead of `return view('leave.show', ['leavereqs' => Leave::where('leavenr', $leavenr)->first()]);` it works as expected. Is it possible that Laravel is caching the app.blade.php file and not actually refreshing it when it redirects to a different page, causing the count not to update?

Comment: Can we see the ->markAsRead() function?

Comment: @Petay87 The markAsRead() method is the default method that Laravel's Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable trait uses. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#marking-notifications-as-read